# Android XML Scrollview

Tags: android, xml, textview, scrollview, lorem-ipsum

I'm trying to put multiple `TextViews` below eachother in one `ScrollView`, but when I do this it makes my App crash. How can I put the same text twice underneath eachother?

```
  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/linear">

    <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"/>

    <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"/>
  </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you post your full xml file ?

Comment: You can put only one child in`ScrollView` so use `LinearLayout` or any other Container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per android docmentaion :-

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects. A child that is often used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting a vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through.

**Scrollview always contains only one child layout. And Linear layout have orientation property to manage child layout either horizontal or vertical**.

Your code must be look like as following:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical" >
         <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"/>

         <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"/>
   </LinearLayout></ScrollView>
```

I think the above code helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Your [Scrollview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) can have **only one child view**, so put a layout and your textviews inside this layout:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/linear">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"/>

    </LinearLayout> 

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: This is not right, it will be unmeaning-full if u put the height to match_parent for a scroll view..

Comment: That's right, I can now scroll a million miles without having any content. Any way to fix this?

Comment: @Helix. What is the issue now?

Comment: I can keep scrolling and scrolling down while there is no content inside. Looks like it takes the maximum scrollable space possible or something. I have a small piece of lorem ipsum in it, when I scrolled down and its gone, I can keep scrolling while there's nothing to see like @DJphy said

Comment: @RishiPaul answer seems more meaningfull, thumbs up for u...Try that helix

Answer (score 1):

The direct child of ScrollView should be another layout that supports multiple children, such as RelativeLayout or LinearLayout.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Scroll View Can Have Only One Child. So Use LinearLayout inside your ScrollView and then inside that do whatever you want to be. Like this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />
</LinearLayout>
```